# Neo4j - How to emulate MySQL multiple schema deployment in Neo4j

Tags: mysql, neo4j, multiple-schema

With single instance of Neo4j server ( not embedded), how to add multiple schema kind of deployment ( similar to MySQL) in Neo4j ?
How is it possible to add / delete schema run time in Neo4j deployed as a server?

Comment: There is no solution for this yet? Very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate each table to a node type, columns to node's (or relationship) properties and foreign keys to relationships (here you can store more properties).

Neo4j is schema free, but What you can do in Neo4j is create nodes linked to your root node, each one representing a "class". If you link all the instances to the "class" node you can navigate through them like iterating in a SQL-like table or know the "schema" that follows this node.

Here is an example about how to model categories from SQL to Neo4j:
http://blog.neo4j.org/2010/03/modeling-categories-in-graph-database.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have a constraint where data from different schema ( in mysql terminology) should be segregated.

Comment: It is schema-free, like MongoDB. But here you do not have collections.
If you use OrientDB (another graph database) instead of Neo4j you can define some schemas or leave it free (it is mixed).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check OrientDB.